# Upload an updated app version using Xcode in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ipa

I have already uploaded an app which has been rejected by Apple. Then I fixed the error, increased the version in the `config.xml`, I made a new Archive and after the process, I got the message (in Xcode) 'Uploaded Successful'.

Then I go to iTunesConnect but I cannot see my new version in the 'Activity' tab.

The total size of the app is 20MB.

Do I have to do anything in iTunesConnect in order to apply the new version or the newly uploaded version appears automatically? 
Is it normal that after 1 hour nothing has been uploaded?

The new build version does not appear in the iOS Builds in the Activity tab.

Comment: What do you mean by increase the version in `Config.xml`? Usually, when uploading a new build of same version, you just need to increment the build number... If you incremented the version number, It might not come up, because the version doesn't exist on ItunesConnect

Comment: i mean the config.xml in ionic. i build an ionic project. i dont have to increase the value?

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-do-you-handle-version-and-build-numbers/102274/6... Go through the versioning... You never mentioned that Ionic was being used... The primary goal is to increase the build number,,, not the version number.

Comment: So if I understand right the steps that I done are, In xcode in 'General' I increase the build number and I left version the same. also in config.xml i do not change the value.

Comment: Were you able to validate the IPA, using the XCode tool?

Comment: Yes. The .ipa was validated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `ios-CFBundleVersion` in your `config.xml`. This will update the iOS **Build** number, which is required to be different if you want to upload multiple builds under the same version number to iTunesConnect.
    
    `<!-- iOS -->
    <widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" ios-CFBundleVersion="0.1.3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    </widget>`

Comment: Hello. I have already in config.xml , <widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">. I need to add another one or to edit the one that exists?

Comment: `version` is not the same as `ios-CFBundleVersion`

Comment: So 0.1.3 means that i am in version 1 build 3 ?

Comment: Apple uses two separate identifiers for version and build number. For instance, in Xcode, you see the version as **Version 10.0 (10A255)**. The version number is **10.0**, the build number is **10A255**. For the same release, all build numbers must be unique, but they can be repeated across different releases. If you want more information about Apple versioning you could refer to their documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2420/_index.html